# How to export the network panel logs from Chrome in a HAR file?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to export the network panel logs from Chrome in a HAR file in a Java Selenium Webdriver. I'm able to do this manually by going to Chrome's Developer Tools, Network Panel, then right-clicking and selecting Export. Is there a way to do this using options or capabilities? Same I have already done with Firefox browser and I don't want any solution using Phantom.js.